# Generating Difference in Days with String dates

Tags: stata, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I have a dataset in Stata that looks as follows, with all variables in String type.

```
registration_date   judgement_date      Case_type
26jul1981           03may2002           Criminal case
19oct1982           23dec2003           Civil case
24jul1983           17dec2018           Criminal case
19oct2000           23dec2002           Criminal case
19oct2002           23dec2012           Small claims case
```

I would like to generate a variable for the average time in days it takes to resolve a case per case type. For instance, I want a new variable that shows the following as an example:

```
registration_date   judgement_date      Case_type               Average_in_days_Case_type
26jul1981           03may2002           Criminal case                        3000 days
19oct1982           23dec2003           Civil case                           1200 days   
24jul1983           17dec2018           Criminal case                        3000 days
19oct2000           23dec2002           Criminal case                        3000 days
19oct2002           23dec2012           Small claims case                    200 days
```

This is my code thus far:

```
generate judgement_date_numeric=date(judgement_date,"DMY") 
generate registration_date_numeric=date(registration_date,"DMY") 

// Changing the format into readable dates
format judgement_date_numeric %d 
format registration_date_numeric %d 


// Generate a variable for the average time in days it takes to resolve a case per case Category
gen waiting_days = judgement_date_numeric - registration_date_numeric[_n-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
// Convert the date variables from String format, into a date variable 
generate judgement_date_numeric=date(judgement_date,"DMY") 
generate registration_date_numeric=date(registration_date,"DMY") 

// Changing the format into readable dates
format judgement_date_numeric %d 
format registration_date_numeric %d 


// Generate a variable for the average time in days it takes to resolve a case per case Category
gen waiting_days = judgement_date_numeric - registration_date_numeric[_n-1]
```